# Python nosetests no such option --html--report how to generate the html report

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose

I have a Selenium Python regression test script.  My HTMLTestRunner is not working to generate the test report.  I am now trying to use the Nose plugin to generate a HTML report.

I have installed Nose and pip install nose-html-reporting

I am trying the following command in windows cmd to run my test script and generate the report.

```
nosetests.exe e:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test\ClearCore\Regression TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py --with-html --html-report=nose_report.html
```

I get the following error:

```
nosestests: error: no such option: --html-report
```

Could someone show me an example command I could use to run my test script and output the html report?

I have got it to work now. I have used the following command

```
nosetests.exe e:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test\ClearCore\Regression TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py --with-html --html-file=e:\report.html
```

Is there a way I can add this command to my test script e.g. In the Main part?  So i can run it through the PyCharm IDE?
I would also like to add a date to the report file name.  When the tests run overnight it would be good to have a date in the file name.
How can i do this please?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the nose-html-reporting plugin is not installed yet.

```
pip install nose-html-reporting
```

Below command prints the list of installed plugins to check.

```
nosetests --plugins
```

Comment: Just found PyCharm question in original topic. Noses tests is supported by PyCharm and the configuration items are located at Menu->Run->Run/Debug Configurations->Python tests. 
Here is the link for official document, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-nose-test.html